# What is the mean and variance of $Y$, where $Y$ is sum of iid's

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables, expectation

[image: Convergence in Probability]

Here's my work for part a. I could use clarification on part b and d. Is part d the same as part a ($E[A_n] = E[Y]$) ?

a)
$$E[Y_n] = E[\frac{X_n}{2^n}]$$ ($X$'s are iid so...) $$= \frac{E[X]}{2^n} = \frac2{2^n}$$

$$Var(Y_n) = \frac{Var(X_n)}{4^n} = \frac9{4^n}$$

b) $E[T_n] = E[\sum_{i=0}^n Y_i] = E[1 + \frac12 + \frac14 + ... + \frac2{2^n}] = E[\frac1{1-\frac12}] = 2$

Is this correct?

Comment: Is $T_n$, the **sum** of the $Y_i$, given by $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ or $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2$?

Comment: Sum of the Y_i. My mistake, did not mean to write ^2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have for b is wrong this is because 
$$E[T_{n}]=E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i}\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}E[Y_{i}]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{2}{2^{i}}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2^{i-1}}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2^{i}}$$

Now here you also attempted to use fact about a geometric series, but remember n is finite here (it is not approaching infinity like it does in a geometric series). Thus we actually have (which is derived here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Proof_of_convergence)
$$=\frac{1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=2\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)$$

For further use of this, i guess you would call it, "finite geometric sum" the property is that 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}ar^{i}=a\frac{1-r^{n}}{1-r}$$ 
where you must make sure indices and such are exactly the same form to use this exact result.

Comment: Also note for a) you say "$X_{i}$'s are iid so..", the properties you use following do not require any iid aspects, this will come into play for finding variance in (b) and (c)

Comment: So is $var(T_n)$ and $var(A_n)$ = $\frac{9n}{4^n} and \frac9{n*4^n}$, respectively?

Comment: Var(Tn) should equal $3(1-\frac{1}{4^{n}})$ and $Var(An)=Var(\frac{Tn}{n})=\frac{1}{n^{2}}Var(Tn)$, I think you are trying to evoke property that for $W_{i}$ iid rvs (thus all have same variance) that $Var(\sum_{i=1}^{n}W_{i})=n\sigma^{2}$, but notice that $Y_{i}$'s aren't iid

Comment: (namely not identically distributed)

Comment: Understood. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: Yea its definitely something to get easily confused, just remember if you are dealing with iid many properties that make these computations easy can't be used so you have be careful when doing problem

Comment: Please delete the $a$ in your last displayed equation, or insert an $a$ on the right hand side.

Comment: @dilipSarwate thanks for that catch